# Ruby catch all exception class

Tags: ruby, exception

How can i catch all exception in ruby class like this:

```
class ServiceException
rescue => e
   puts 'Error!!!'
end

class ServiceA < ServiceException
   def say_hello
      error_code_here
   end
end

ServiceA.new.say_hello
# => Error!!!
```

Answer (score 4):

OK so i managed do accomplish this with some metaprogramming. First define this module:

```
module MetaprogrammingStuff

  def rescue_all_methods(klass, *errors_to_rescue, &blk)
    patch_all_methods(klass) do |orig_method, *args, &caller_blk|
      begin
        orig_method.call *args, &caller_blk
      rescue *errors_to_rescue => e
        blk.call e
      end
    end
  end

  def patch_all_methods(klass, &blk)
    patch_class_methods(klass, &blk)
    patch_instance_methods(klass, &blk)
  end

  def patch_class_methods(klass, &blk)
    klass.methods(false).each do |fn_name|
      orig_method = klass.method fn_name
      klass.singleton_class.send(:define_method, fn_name) do |*args, &caller_blk|
        blk.call orig_method, *args, &caller_blk
      end
    end
  end

  def patch_instance_methods(klass, &blk)
    klass.instance_methods(false).each do |fn_name|
      orig_method = klass.instance_method fn_name
      klass.send(:define_method, fn_name) do |*args, &caller_blk|
        blk.call orig_method.bind(self), *args, &caller_blk
      end
    end
  end

end
```

then extend it to a class and run `rescue_all_methods`:

```
class TestClass
  extend MetaprogrammingStuff
  def foo
    raise ArgumentError
  end
  def self.foo
    raise RuntimeError
  end
  rescue_all_methods(self, ArgumentError, RuntimeError) do |error|
    puts "#{error.class} was raised."
  end
end
```

It's important that `rescue_all_methods` be called after the methods are defined.

You can see it inserts a rescue block around all instance and class methods:

```
TestClass.foo
# => RuntimeError was raised.

TestClass.new.foo
# => ArgumentError was raised.
```

How it works - basically it turns the methods into anonymous fuctions using the `method` and `instance_method` methods, then re-assigns those method names to new methods which call the original but with a begin..rescue wrapper.